# Able to push to all git remotes with the one command?

Tags: git

Instead of doing:

```
git push origin --all && git push nodester --all && git push duostack --all
```

Is there a way to do that with just one command?

Thanks :)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5620525/223092

Comment: To create a `all` remote to push on all your remotes see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18637593/802365

Answer (score 344, accepted):

#### To push all branches to all remotes:

```
git remote | xargs -L1 git push --all
```

#### Or if you want to push the current branch to all remotes:

```
git remote | xargs -L1 -I R git push R
```

#### (Bonus) To make a git alias for the command:

```
git config --global alias.pushall '!git remote | xargs -L1 git push --all'
```

Running `git pushall` will now push all branches to all remotes.

Comment: Very good and simple solution. BTW you can use xargs -l instead of -L 1, the -l option is the same as -L 1. Also, sometimes I add --all to the git push. git remote | xargs -l git push --all

Comment: I get `xargs: illegal option -- l` on OSX. Figured it out, you need `git remote | xargs -L1 git push`

Comment: Git allows you to make that call into a custom command. Just put it in a file that 1) is on your path, 2) you have execute permissions for, and 3) called "git-[custom name]" (e.g. git-foo, git-push-all) and you'll be able to simply type "git [custom name]" (e.g. git foo, git push-all).

Comment: @Tony On Ubuntu, `man xargs` says option `-l` is deprecated since it's not in the POISX spec.

Comment: what does `!` in alias?

Comment: @kyb In git alias syntax, `!` means the following is not an internal git command, but an external shell command.

Comment: note `xargs -I` implies `-L1`. 2nd expression could be shorten.

Comment: macOS 10.15.3 I get `xargs: push: No such file or directory` when using `-I` but works fine for using `-L1`

Comment: `git remote | xargs -t -I % git push '%' main` is success on windows.

Comment: if you're in powershell `git remote | ForEach-Object {git push --all $_}`

Comment: This has one pitfall. If `git branch` would return at first not a default branch and the remote repository is not yet exist, but a hub supports a repo creation on first push, then it will make the first branch accidentally the default and additionally protected from, for example, a force push (gitlab). Then you have to fix that later.

Answer (score 356):

Create an `all` remote with several repo URLs to its name:

```
git remote add all origin-host:path/proj.git
git remote set-url --add all nodester-host:path/proj.git
git remote set-url --add all duostack-host:path/proj.git
```

Then just `git push all --all`.

---

This is how it looks in `.git/config`:

```
  [remote "all"]
  url = origin-host:path/proj.git
  url = nodester-host:path/proj.git
  url = duostack-host:path/proj.git
```

Comment: Super cool trick! The only disadvantage is that it does not move remote heads. You need to run `git fetch --all` right after doing such push.

Comment: Mr. Torvalds (creator of Git) mentions that he uses this method, but he states that it is merely for convenience and offers no technical advantage http://marc.info/?l=git&m=116231242118202&w=2  

"And in the end, even a "git push all" that pushes to multiple repositories will actually end up connecting once for each repository, so it's really just a shorthand for doing multiple "git push"es. There's no real technical advantage, just a convenience."

Comment: One problem with this approach is that you have to add new URLs to the `all` remote as they become available, whereas `git remote | xargs -L1 git push --all` will automatically pick up any new remotes.

Comment: Tip: To no need typing `all` whenever you send a commit, just use "origin" instead of "all": `git remote set-url --add origin nodester-host:path/proj.git`

Comment: forgot to set the push urls otherwise `git push` won't update all the urls.  answer updated accordingly

Comment: never-mind answer update rejected: just remember to do `git remote set-url --add --push all duostack-host:path/proj.git` otherwise it won't push to that url.

Comment: the corresponding push config setting looks like `pushurl = duostack-host:path/proj.git`

Comment: The advantage to this answer is that it is about git itself

Comment: this is great...
after this how do you remove one from the `all` group?

Comment: Same way you added it? Just delete the line from the `.git/config` file…

Answer (score 141):

If you want to always push to repo1, repo2, and repo3 but always pull only from repo1, set up the remote 'origin' as

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://exampleuser@example.com/path/to/repo1
    pushurl = https://exampleuser@example.com/path/to/repo1
    pushurl = https://exampleuser@example.com/path/to/repo2
    pushurl = https://exampleuser@example.com/path/to/repo3
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Configure at command line:

```
$ git remote add origin https://exampleuser@example.com/path/to/repo1
$ git remote set-url --push --add origin https://exampleuser@example.com/path/to/repo1
$ git remote set-url --push --add origin https://exampleuser@example.com/path/to/repo2
$ git remote set-url --push --add origin https://exampleuser@example.com/path/to/repo3
```

If you *only* want to pull from `repo1` but push to `repo1` and `repo2` *for a specific branch `specialBranch`*:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://git@aaa.xxx.com:7999/yyy/repo1.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    ...
[remote "specialRemote"]
    url = ssh://git@aaa.xxx.com:7999/yyy/repo1.git
    pushurl = ssh://git@aaa.xxx.com:7999/yyy/repo1.git
    pushurl = ssh://git@aaa.xxx.com:7999/yyy/repo2.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    ...
[branch "specialBranch"]
    remote = origin
    pushRemote = specialRemote
    ...
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-branchltnamegtremote.

Comment: I'm not sure why this hasn't got more votes. This is actually really convenient because it allows you to just do a `git push` without any arguments.

Comment: Vote for me, please!

Comment: This seems to me more appropriate way to do this. Should've had the highest votes.

Comment: It is very usefull. Is it possible to limit pushurl to master branch only?

Comment: @fbucek: I added the answer to your question in the OP.

Comment: For those that after use this it didn't push to repo1 (the main repo to fetch), don't forget to also `git remote set-url --push --add origin` to repo1. Anyway, `use git remote -v` to check your remotes.

Answer (score 20):

As a CLI Alternative to editing the .git/config file, you could use the following commands:

```
# git remote add all origin-host:path/proj.git
# git remote set-url --add all nodester-host:path/proj.git
# git remote set-url --add all duostack-host:path/proj.git
```

The same `git push all --all` works here as well.

You have accomplished the same as answer #1. You have just done it with Command Line instead of raw editing of the config file.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a short bash function to push to many remotes in one call. You can specify a single remote as a parameter, multiple remotes separated by spaces or don't specify any to have it push to all remotes.

This can be added to your .bashrc or .bash_profile.

```
function GitPush {
  REMOTES=$@

  # If no remotes were passed in, push to all remotes.
  if [[ -z "$REMOTES" ]]; then
    REM=`git remote`

    # Break the remotes into an array
    REMOTES=$(echo $REM | tr " " "\n")
  fi

  # Iterate through the array, pushing to each remote
  for R in $REMOTES; do
    echo "Pushing to $R..."
    git push $R
  done
}
```

Example: Let's say your repo has 3 remotes: rem1, rem2 and rem3.

```
# Pushes to rem1
GitPush rem1

# Pushes to rem1 and rem2
GitPush rem1 rem2

# Pushes to rem1, rem2 and rem3
GitPush
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) - especially `pre-push`: add non-origin pushes to `.git/hooks/pre-push`.

Answer (score -1):

If you already have an existing repository with `origin` as the default remote and want to push to multiple remote repositories by just calling `git push` (or with the git sync button of your IDE / text editor) first add the current `origin` URL (that is used for all operations e.g. `push`, `pull`, `fetch`) as a push-specific remote origin URL:

```sh
git remote set-url --push --add origin "$(git remote get-url --push origin)"
```

... and then add each other remote repository to the push-specific URLs like that:

```sh
git remote set-url --push --add origin "git@github.com:username/repo-name.git"
```

Now all fetch and pull operations will only fetch from your original remote repository.

But with a simple `git push` git pushes your latest changes to all remote repositories you've added right now.