# Heroku is it possible to add git repository to github?

Tags: heroku, github

Is it possible to add heroku git repository to github?

Example I have a Heroku git:

git@heroku.com:myapp.git

Can I somehow add this to github? So I can see want files are on the server and follow changes etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add another remote to your clone that points to your github account/repository and then push to that repository as well when you make changes. You'll have to make sure though, that you always push to both remotes.

Comment: So I always need to do 2 push commands? Is there not a better way to do this?

Comment: I do 2 pushes with my project on openshift/bitbucket and I like that I can know my data safe without having to update the code on openshift. There are ways to do one push only though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785549/able-to-push-to-all-git-remotes-with-the-one-command

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set up git to push to two repositories simultaneously.

Please see this post here: [Pushing to Multiple Git Repositories Simultaneously](http://jeetworks.org/node/22)