# how to push in git repository a files to all remote branches?

Tags: git

I have a local repository that I have cloned from our remote git repository and I have edited a file in this branch.
now I need to push this specific file to all remote branches?

how can I do it at one command and not insert it manually to each branch?

Comment: git push origin <branch> && git push origin <branch> use and operator to all branches

Comment: Pushing a change to all remote branches sounds like you use git the wrong way.

Comment: "Branches", or "remote repository(ies)"? I assume you mean the latter.

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785549/able-to-push-to-all-git-remotes-with-the-one-command

Comment: why wrong way? there is a file that is used for notifications and I want it be in all the remote branches. I don;t want to do it manually

Answer (score 1):

If you fixed a file on your local branch, it will be pushed to a single remote branch which is the branch upstream.

If you have many remote branches that needs this fix. You need to merge the commit to all those branches. First locally, and then push the changes.

It has to be done manually, or using some script.

```
git checkout some_local_branch
git cherry-pick <hash of the fix>
git checkout another_local_branch
git cherry-pick <hash of the fix>
....
git push
```

The last git push will either push all your branches together or just some branches. That depends on your settings.

Comment: I have roughly around 40 remote branches. all I want is to update a single file in all of them ( same file and I have no problem with running over the previous version of this file in each branch)

Comment: The only way to update a branch is using a commit. If it is the same commit you want to apply, then you merge it or cherry-pick it. And it most be local branch first, and push branches to remote. Assuming no conflicts, I would say that script is the best way.