# i want to push code from local repository to two different repository

Tags: git, github, repository, push

I want to push local repository code to the two different repository using single push command.

Please help me to find it is possible or not.

If possible let me know the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your local git repo is properly setup with the right remotes, you can use the command

```
git push all <branch>
```

It will push your branch to all the remotes

Comment: Syntax error: not `git push all` but `git push --all`. And that doesn't push to all remotes, that pushes all branches to one remote. See the docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---all

Comment: My bad then, try using the answer from this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785549/able-to-push-to-all-git-remotes-with-the-one-command