# Pushing to multiple git remotes but different branches at the same time

Tags: git, branch

I have two local branches:

- master
- development

and 3 remotes:

- git1 with master and development (same as local)
- git2 with master only (equals local master)
- git3 with master only (equals local development)

What I want to do is pushing (preferably with GitKraken) the following, each at once:

- local:master -> git1:master, git2:master
- local:development -> git1:development, git3:master

How can I do this?

I´ve already set up remotes with multiple URLs in git config:

```
[remote "git1_git2"]
    url = git1_url
    url = git2_url
[remote "git1_git3"]
    url = git2_url
    url = git3_url
```

But how can I specify the branches it pushes to for the different urls?

From which remote does it pull when I pull from a multiple url remote?

Answer (score 0):

```bash
# Look at the remote list by typing :
git remote -v 

# >> origin <push>
# >> origin <fetch>

# >> another_origin <push>
# >> another_origin <fetch>
```

```
git push -u origin Development
git push -u another_origin master
```

Also, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620525/git-pushing-to-two-repos-in-one-command).